# Parse file with BASH script and copy pattern match to a variable

Tags: regex, parsing, bash, variables

Say I have a file (php as it happens), with a number of variable declarations:

```
$dbuser = 'fred';
$dppass = 'abc123';
$dhhost = '127.0.0.1';
```

What I want to do from a BASH script, is parse this file, identify the variables I need, and read their values into variables I can access from my BASH script.

Obviously, the above file being PHP, has other lines that I'm not interested in.

I can extract the info I need from the bash shell using the following command:

```
grep \$dbuser config.php.inc | grep -Po "\'.*\'" | cut -d \' -f 2
```

which neatly returns

```
fred
```

But when I try to add this to a bash script to put the output into a variable using backticks, as follows:

```
dbuser=`grep \$dbuser config.php.inc | grep -Po "\'.*\'" | cut -d \' -f 2`
```

my BASH script hangs at this point.

Why is this hanging, or, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return text like `var='value';`

```
awk '
    match($1, /^\$([[:alnum:]_]+)=?/, m){
        gsub(/^[^=]+=[[:space:]]*/, "")
        print m[1] "=" $0
    }
' < file.php
```

You can `eval` the output.

**update**

This is a lot simpler than the above. I realized all you need to do is delete the first `$` and remove the spaces around the `=`:

```
sed -e 's/\$//' -e 's/ *= */=/' file.php
```

Comment: Wow! That's a neat way of doing it. It will fail on a line which makes a call to a mysql_connect function `$db=mysql_connect(...`, but I can easy shift that to a different include to get round that.

Comment: ...and by fail, I mean the `eval` part will fail.

Comment: The `sed` version doesn't work quite as well, as it doesn't cope with the other lines in the file. These include `<?php`, `?>` and comment lines, `ini_set`, `require_once` and a few other PHP specific lines.

Comment: Accepted on the basis of the awk part of the answer, as it deals with all the variables in my config.php.inc, without me having to hard code each variable.

Comment: @Bryan, I was going on your code sample that only showed variable declarations. Glad the awk version worked for you though.

Answer (score 3):

Try it this way:

```
dbuser=$(grep \$dbuser config.php.inc | grep -Po "\'.*\'" | cut -d \' -f 2)
```

The reason this works and the backticks did not is in the way $(command) handles quoting vs. how the old style backticks handles quoting.

In other words, the following backtick command would have worked just as well:

```
dbuser=`grep '$dbuser' config.php.inc | grep -Po "'.*'" | cut -d"'" -f 2`
```

1. Used single quotes to enclose $dbuser since single quotes means use the literal text rather than interpolate it as a shell variable.
2. Removed the escaping from .* since it is not needed.
3. Removed the escaping from the cut command since it is not needed.

BTW, this would have worked as well:

```
dbuser=`grep '$dbuser' config.php.inc | grep -Po "\'.*\'" | cut -d \' -f 2`
```

Additionally, the $(command) syntax is in general the best approach whenever possible. Use `` only for portability reasons if you must support a platform that is absolutely known to not support $(command). This is IMHO very rare, so the rule of thumb is to lean towards $(command) from the start.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?  I think it does work - but it is very subtle.

Comment: Is this a better method than using backticks?

Comment: Essentially, yes, $(command) is the better and more modern approach. Use backticks only when you need to support a platform that is known to not support $(command) which is rare these days. Backticks have issues with less-than-trivial quoting and really fall down when you need to support multiple levels of nested commands. $(command) handles this well.

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation, I wasn't aware of this, and have just always used backticks. I wish I could have accepted all the answers so far to the question, as each one provides a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sound like that there is a missing \

Check if this is not \\$dbuser

If you have access to perl 
try:

```
dbuser=$(perl -ne "print \$1 if /\$dbuser.*'(.*)'/" config.php.inc)
```

Note :
 -e use next parameter as a one liner script
 -n use all parameter as file argument
 print $1 print the matched pattern when matched
 The parathesis in the regex define the $1 capture group.

Comment: Adding the second escape character fixed the problem. I don't have perl available to me at the moment, but might give that a try. Do the parenthesis define that part that is output from match?

Answer (score 1):

With some basic checking and safety

```
eval $(sed -n "s/^\$\([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\) *= *'\(.*\)' *;/\1='\2';/p")
echo User:$dbuser Pass:$dppass Host:$dhhost
```

will print for your example

```
User:fred Pass:abc123 Host:127.0.0.1
```